i want to create fibonacci retracement but i don't know how to set the all time high to calculate
i get all time high
GetAllTimeHigh(dataSeries = high) =>
highestHTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "D",
      GetChartHighest(dataSeries)[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
highestChartTF = GetChartHighest(dataSeries)
math.max(highestHTF, highestChartTF)

plot(series=GetAllTimeHigh(), color=color.green, linewidth=2,
 title="All-Time High")

and i try to use all time high value to show level of fibonacci retracement but after ta.highest is follow by length that the product chart is different number of candle
ath = ta.highest(1000) 

what i should to do with above line?
L382 = ath-(ath*0.382)
L500 = ath-(ath*0.5)
L618 = ath-(ath*0.618)    
L786 = ath-(ath*0.786)   
L887 = ath-(ath*0.887)     
L942 = ath-(ath*0.942)

as i try specific number 1000 and it not good
what i want
ath = ta.highest(total candle for this product in each timeframe)
